# MLRun, Issue with memory request setup (1B) for nuclio function

Tags: python, mlrun, nuclio

I have issue with memory request setup for nuclio function, current memory request has value 1B, see info in Grafana:

[image]

I used this code:

```
fn.add_model("prt-model", class_name="ClassifierPRT", model_path="tst")
fn.apply(mlrun.mount_v3io())

# Set resources
fn.with_http(2)
fn.with_requests(mem="500m", cpu=0.5)
fn.with_limits(mem="1G", cpu=1)

fn.spec.replicas = 2
fn.spec.min_replicas = 2
fn.spec.max_replicas = 2

project.save()
```

Did you have similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the same problem, the issue is, that you use a invalid unit "**500m**", you have to use these quantity suffixes '**E, P, T, G, M, k**' or you can also use the power-of-two equivalents '**Ei, Pi, Ti, Gi, Mi, Ki**'. See official documentation [k8s meaning-of-memory](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#meaning-of-memory).

Relevant value is "**500M**" (x1.000 K) or "**500Mi**" (x 1.024 Ki), updated code, see:

```
...
fn.with_requests(mem="500Mi", cpu=0.5)
fn.with_limits(mem="3G", cpu=2)
...
```